# Ffmpeg Unknown input format: gdigrab

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell

I tried in used this command with `ffmpeg` but it doesn't work.

```
fmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Vnútorný mikrofón (Conexant ISST Audio)" -vcodec libx264 YOUR_NAME_HERE.mp4
```

and this:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -framerate 10 -vcodec libx264 YOUR_NAME_HERE.mp4
```

but it shows two times the same error.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Your ffmpeg build is from 2013. Get a current build.

Comment: The problem is your version of FFmpeg doesn’t support [`gdigrab`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab). Most likely because it is 8+ years old.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answares.

Comment: Didn't worked for me. I have installed the latest version of FFmpeg 4.4 but issue still persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a version of `FFmpeg` that is over 7 years old, and as such, it most likely doesn't support using `gdigrab`. It is a program that is *constantly* receiving updates and you should get the newest version you can, not an old superceded one.

You can download the latest version [here on the FFmpeg website](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) and then you will be able to run the command you specified.

Comment: Why the downvote, am I wrong?

Comment: You are right! O only don't know how this app works).
Thansk for answare

Comment: Didn't worked for me.
I have installed the latest version of FFmpeg 4.4 but issue still persist.